# Unhandled Exception: XmlParserException: "<" expected at 1:1

Tags: flutter

```
  Future<void> a() async {
     ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/e.xlsx");
     var bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
     var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);
  }
```

The bold code reports the error as follows：
Unhandled Exception: XmlParserException: "<" expected at 1:1

Answer (score 0):

The docs mention the usage of `update: true` in case of reading from the assets folder.

https://pub.dev/packages/excel#read-xlsx-from-flutters-asset-folder

```dart
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/e.xlsx");
var bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes, update: true);
```

Can you post the start of `e.xlsx` in plain text?

Comment: If I add "update:true", it will be underlined here. Is it because of the version of the excel package?